# Object doesn't support this property EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I know what this error is, but I can't figure out why it is being called. I ran the scrip to the cursor and it seems to break on lin 6 [Title = Application....]. What about my code isn't supported in VBA?

```
Function Term_gen()
    TermRow = 3    \\Starting Row on Term Tab    
    ResultsRow = 3  'Starting Row on Results tab
    Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("Results").Range("A:A").Value) 'Loop through a column in "Results" tab until cells are blank

        Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("Terms").Range("N:N").Value) 'Loop through column in "Terms" tab until cells are blank


            Lefty = Left(Worksheets("Terms").Range("N" & TermRow).Value, 6) 'Take left 6 letters in the designated cell
            Location = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Lefty, Worksheets("Results").Range("ResultsRow:ResultsRow"), 0) 'Use the match function to find the location of the string found in  Lefty, in the row designated    

        If Location IsError Then 'If the tern Row produces an error

            TermRow =  TermRow + 1  'Go to the next Row in Terms and reset loop
        Else

                    Title = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Results").Range("A1:CR200000"), Location, ResultsRow) 'Store the value of the term found in the row 
        Loop 'End the loop

        whole_name = Title & Worksheets("Results").Range("X1").Value 'Concatinate the Title Value with a fixed value in spreadsheet

    If whole_name IsError Then 'If the Vlookup Produces an error
            TermRow = TermRow + 1 'Go to next row in Terms and reset loop
    Else

                 term = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(whole_name, Worksheets("Terms").Range("N:O"), 2, 1) 'Vlookup of the whole term in the term sheet

                 Worksheets("Test_Sheet").Range("A" & ResultsRow).Value = term 'Print Term in designated cell


                 ResultsRow = ResultsRow + 1 'Go to next row. Start loop over.

Loop
End Function
```

Comment: You are passing to the first parameter of Match `Application.WorksheetFunction.Left(Worksheets("Terms"), Range("N:N").Value, 6)` which is invalid.  What do you expect this to be?

Comment: In Excel the formula would be typed out as follows: {=MATCH(LEFT(Terms!N3,6),Results!3:3)} 

I'm checking the first 6 letters of the N column in the "Terms" tab and finding the matching column in the Results tab.

Comment: I just updated the line thinking it would work, It didn't.

Application.WorksheetFunction.Left(Worksheets("Terms").Range("N" & Row).Value, 6)

Comment: A simpler way to figure this out would be to do one function at a time and store the result in a variable, instead of nesting functions inside of other functions. Once you know which function is actually causing the function, you can address it.

Comment: `Left` isn't available as a method of `WorksheetFunction` (the "Object" the error refers to is `WorksheetFunction`).  Instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Left` just use `Left`.  Another point, don't bother with the `.Value`'s in the Location and Title lines, just leave them out (I get an Out of Memory error if they are left in)

Comment: Your whole code is a junk! since no loop is required when you are using built-in functions.  So please describe in words about each steps to know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I started making notes and realized you might be right. But I'm not sure it is because of the loops.I made  few edits, but I'm new to VBA. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The idea is to retrieve a value via a Vlookup in a semi-circular way. I find the value that fits in one the terms  tab, and if it is in the row, I do a vlookup of the term concatenated with a fixed value. If the fixed value has an error, the loop starts over again. Else, it prints the result, and moves on to the next row. I'm posting the new code with documentation on the next comment.

Comment: It's too. Long. I'm editing my OP instead.